# Determine all values of k so real part is equal to zero (complex numbers)

Tags: complex-numbers

having some real trouble finding out how to solve this equation. Quite stuck on it, any ideas to push me into the right direction or a method to solve this?

Find all values of $k \in \Bbb Z$ so next formula is satisfied:

$$Re(z_1(z_2)^k)=0$$

Given is: $z_1=\sqrt3e^{(5\pi/6)i} $ and $z_2=2e^{(\pi/6)i+\ln(\sqrt3)} $.

I've calculated the real and imaginary parts to be:
$Re(z_1)=-3/2, Im(z_1)=\sqrt3/2, Re(z_2)=3, Im(z_2)=\sqrt3$

No clue how to continue from this point on.

Comment: Try writing all of these in Cis form. The real part of a complex number is 0 iff the angle is (what values?) .

Comment: @CalvinLin thank you. Using this method I found $\sqrt3*cis((5*\pi)/6)$ where each $k = 0,1,2,3...$ added a $\pi/6$ on top of the cis term (if this is mathematically speaking correct). I found out it would give $k=-2+6n$ where $n \in \Bbb Z$ (so the cis term would be $\pi/2+m*\pi$ where $m \in \Bbb Z$), same answer as Bonnaduck. Thanks!

Comment: It may be noted that since $ \ z_1·z_2 \ = \ \sqrt3 · 2 \sqrt3 · cis \left(\frac{5 \pi}{6}  +  \frac{\pi}{6} \right) \ = \ 6·cis(\pi) \ = \ -6 \ \ , \ $ we really only need to look at when $ \ z_2^{(k  -  1) } \ $ is purely imaginary.  This occurs for $$ (k \ - \ 1)·\frac{\pi}{6} \ \ = \ \ (2n \ + \ 1)·\frac{\pi}{2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ k \ - \ 1 \ \ = \ \ 6n \ + \ 3  \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ k \ \ = \ \ 4 \ + \ 6n \ \ , \ \ n \ \in \ \mathbb{Z} \ \ , $$ as other posters have found.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We want to write our complex numbers of the form $re^{i\theta}$, where $r,\theta\in\Bbb R$. $z_1$ is already in this form, and we can change $z_2$ into this form by writing it as $z_2=2\sqrt3e^{i\pi/6}$.

Recall that for any $z\in\Bbb C$, $Re(z)=\frac{z+\bar z}{2}$. Moreover, recall that if $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\bar z=re^{-i\theta}$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
Re(z_1(z_2)^k)&=\frac{z_1(z_2)^k+\overline{z_1(z_2)^k}}{2}\\
&=\frac{z_1(z_2)^k+\bar{z_1}(\bar{z_2})^k}{2}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt3e^{i5\pi/6}(2\sqrt3e^{i\pi/6})^k+\sqrt3e^{-i5\pi/6}(2\sqrt3e^{-i\pi/6})^k}{2}\\
&=\sqrt3\cdot\frac{(2\sqrt3)^ke^{i5\pi/6}e^{ik\pi/6}+(2\sqrt3)^ke^{-i5\pi/6}e^{-ik\pi/6}}2\\
&=\sqrt3(2\sqrt3)^k\cdot\frac{e^{i(5\pi/6+k\pi/6)}+e^{-i(5\pi/6+ik\pi/6)}}2\\
&=\sqrt3(2\sqrt3)^k\cdot\frac{e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta}}2\\
&=\sqrt3(2\sqrt3)^k\cos\theta\\
\end{align*}

where $\theta=5\pi/6+k\pi/6$. Setting this equal to $0$ gives us

\begin{align*}
\sqrt3(2\sqrt3)^k\cos\theta=0&\iff\cos\theta=0\\
&\iff\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi&n\in\Bbb Z
\end{align*}

Hence,

\begin{align*}
\frac{5\pi}6+\frac{k\pi}6=\frac{\pi}{2}+n\pi&\iff k=-2+6n&n\in\Bbb Z
\end{align*}